# How to release instance vars and then reuse them

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macos

I have an object in my app that is declared as an instance var.

```
URLRequest * myRequest
```

When I go to use this class I:

```
myRequest = [[URLRequest alloc] init];
```

Then when I am done with it I:

```
[myRequest release];//or dealloc does the same
```

Here is the more of the code: https://gist.github.com/1177739 
It's to much to past here.

However, when I go to use the class again, it goes though the alloc and init, but my app crashes.

pointer being freed was not allocated

I don't understand this because I alloc and init again.  If I don't release, I get memory leaks in my app.  Thanks

Comment: What methods are these in - let us see the minimum code to reproduce - in getting the minimum you might well be able to see the issue yourself

Comment: I have to comment on your comment. You NEVER call dealloc except when subclassing dealloc method and calling [super dealloc]. Never. Ever. And no, it's not the same as release, release decreases retainCount of an object, while dealloc destroys it (automatically) when retainCount reaches 0. And about your question, please tell us more, where do you alloc and release this?

Comment: @Luke: Setting a pointer to `nil` means that you can no longer message the object; that means you can't release it, and you have a leak. Setting a pointer to `nil` _after_ releasing is sometimes done to ensure that you don't accidentally message a deallocated object.

Comment: @Mike007: I doubt many people will go to GitHub nad read through all the code. Please post the relevant parts in your question. Just edit the question and copy and paste the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe your method

```
- (void)urlComplete:(NSNotification *)notification
```

is being called twice, set urlRequest to bill and then test that it is not nil at the beginning of you

```
- (void)urlComplete:(NSNotification *)notification
```

method

Comment: I am calling it twice that is the problem. I hit the button once to make a request, my calls gets instantiated and the request gets made.  After that the class gets released.  Then I hit a button again to make the request again, and it errors saying that my class, "pointer being freed was not allocated".  I don't understand because you can see in my getExtIP, I: urlRequest = [[CMURLRequest alloc] init]; do that again.  But the next time I call urlRquest, it crashes.

Comment: Well thats your problem you are trying to release urlRequest twice set it to nil when  you release it then you can either use that to test that the method needs to execute again or just let the fact that sending a message to nil is a no opp.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, that works.  Everything working well and no memory leaks now.